# Why am i getting a ctrl-J on the end of this PHP generated line?

Tags: php, newline, echo

Im trying to generate a Java WebStart JNLP file from PHP.  I'll put the whole code at the end, but my specific problem is this line of PHP:

```
<property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
<?php
     echo "<property name=\"javaws.username\" value=\"" . $userid . "\" />"  
?>
<property name="server.port" value="3000" />
```

The PHP generated line, I discovered after much struggling, is coming out with a ctrl-J on the end.  This totally screws up Webstart. Why is it doing this and how do I stop it?  The execution environment for the PHP is PHP5 on OpenSolaris.

The full code for this file is below for reference.  (Dont pay any attention to the Windows section, I'm working on a Mac. I'll fix it once the mac section works correctly.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://fgdztgab.joyent.us/snowmen" href="snowman.php">
 <information>
    <title>Snowman</title>
    <vendor>The RedDwarf Project</vendor>
    <description kind="one-line">Game</description>
    <description kind="short">Project Snowman Demo RedDwarf Game</description>
    <description kind="tooltip">Project Snowman</description>
    <shortcut online="false"><desktop/><menu submenu="Project Snowman"/></shortcut>
 </information>
 <security>
 <all-permissions/>
 </security>

 <resources os="Mac" >
    <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="1024m" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
    <?php 
         echo "<property name=\"javaws.username\" value=\"" . $userid . "\" />" 
    ?>  
    <property name="server.port" value="3000" />
    <property name="server.host" value="fgdztgab.joyent.us" />
    <nativelib href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-macbinaries.jar"/>

<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-jnlp-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/sgs-client-0.10.1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/sgs-shared-1.12.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/mina-core-1.1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/slf4j-api-1.4.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/slf4j-jdk14-1.4.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-common-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-terrain-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-audio-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-collada-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-effects-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-font-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-gamestates-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-model-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-scene-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-xml-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/lwjgl-2.0rc2.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/lwjgl_util-2.0rc2.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jorbis-0.0.17.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/fenggui-1.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/environmentsystem-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/md5importer-1.2.4.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-winbinaries.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-macbinaries.jar"/>

 </resources>
 <resources os="Windows" >
    <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="1024m" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="client.username" value="<?php echo($_GET['userid']); ?>" />
    <property name="server.port" value="3000" />
    <property name="server.host" value="fgdztgab.joyent.us" />
    <nativelib href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-winbinaries.jar"/>

<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-jnlp-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/sgs-client-0.10.1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/sgs-shared-1.12.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/mina-core-1.1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/slf4j-api-1.4.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/slf4j-jdk14-1.4.0.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-common-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-terrain-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-audio-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-collada-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-effects-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-font-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-gamestates-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-model-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-scene-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jme-xml-2.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/lwjgl-2.0rc2.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/lwjgl_util-2.0rc2.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/jorbis-0.0.17.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/fenggui-1.0-S1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/environmentsystem-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/md5importer-1.2.4.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-winbinaries.jar"/>
<jar href="projectsnowman/snowman-client-0.2-SNAPSHOT-macbinaries.jar"/>

 </resources>
 <application-desc main-class="com.sun.darkstar.example.snowman.ClientApplication">
 </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Isn't `^J` just a standard `'\n'` new line? Try running the whole file through `dos2unix` (sometimes on systems as `dtox` or `d2u`).

Comment: No can do, this is being generated as dynamic output from a web request.

Answer (score 0):

Set your editor to NOT generate or save .php files with a new line at the end.

Comment: Thats not the issue.  The issue is output from the echo command at script-run time, which appends a ctrl-J

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to heredoc format which moved the unwanted nl to the end of the file where it is annoying but harmless.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer, to remove it from the 'unanswered questions' list. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
<?php echo "<property name=\"javaws.username\" value=\"" . $userid . "\" />";?>  
<property name="server.port" value="3000" />
```

Also, shouldn't there be a `;` on the end of that line?

Comment: Semi-colomn is optional since there is only one line.  And Im afraid that still genreates the ctrl-J.  It seems echo ALWAYS generats a ctrl-J at the end.  I sort of fixed it by moving to the heredoc format so the ctrl-J was at the end.

Comment: Then how about this: `<property name="javaws.username" value="<?php echo $userid;?>" />` where you don't echo the whole line, you just echo the userid into value.